# DTS folder is missing in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working on a project .. and I need to run a PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs.job. The job is failing because the job script includes a path

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.EXE
```

but when I checked my SQL server folder there was no folder named DTS,BINN available, and also DTEXEC.EXE is not available.

to run the job first I had to to include a PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs.dtsx file in SSIS, I have added that and after that I run the below given query to create the job (PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs).. The job got created successfully, but when I am running it is is giving me error:

```
 The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x2803DE2628DAC647946CFAD44DCFF854 
(reason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.
```

Can anyone help me out. here is the code for that job:

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs]    Script Date:     07/21/2016 13:19:18 ******/
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
 DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
 SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
 /****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]]    Script Date: 07/21/2016 13:19:18 ******/
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE      name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
 BEGIN
 EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

 END

  DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
 EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job       @job_name=N'PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
    @notify_level_email=0, 
    @notify_level_netsend=0, 
    @notify_level_page=0, 
    @delete_level=0, 
    @description=N'No description available.', 
    @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
    @owner_login_name=N'App_Profiles10', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
 /****** Object:  Step [PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs.dtsx]    Script Date:    07/21/2016 13:19:18 ******/
 EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId,    @step_name=N'PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs.dtsx', 
    @step_id=1, 
    @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
    @on_success_action=1, 
    @on_success_step_id=0, 
    @on_fail_action=2, 
    @on_fail_step_id=0, 
    @retry_attempts=0, 
    @retry_interval=0, 
    @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
    @command=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.EXE   /SQL "\PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs" /SERVER MSKAN\SQL2008  /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /SET "\Package.Variables[ServerName].Value";MSKAN\SQL2008 /SET "\Package.Variables[DatabaseName].Value";ProfilesRNS /REPORTING E', 
    @flags=0
 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
 EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
 EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
 COMMIT TRANSACTION
 GOTO EndSave
 QuitWithRollback:
 IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 EndSave:

 GO
```

Comment: Maybe this command is failing: `@command=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.EXE   /SQL "\PubMedDisambiguation_GetPubs" /SERVER MSKAN\SQL2008  /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /SET "\Package.Variables[ServerName].Value";MSKAN\SQL2008 /SET "\Package.Variables[DatabaseName].Value";ProfilesRNS /REPORTING E',`

Comment: ya , I know because the DTS folder is not available, do you know how can we install this DTS package ?

Comment: Create an Script Task that checks for the folder to exist....if not, assuming that you are working on a intranet, create the directory and copy the DTEXEC.EXE program into it before running the job creation...

Comment: Is SSIS installed, or do you have a different version of SQL Server Which means you need to look for path 110 or 120. Alternatively did you install on the d:/ or e:/

Comment: I found it, It is on my E drive and DTS is there, but I don't think so DTEXEX.exe is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most production servers the installation of services and software is on a separate drive from the operating system.

So instead of

```
 Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.EXE
```

Have a look for the software on d:/ or e:/

Do you have a different version of SQL Server Which means you need to look for path 110 or 120

Comment: Thanks Mike, this helps. It was there all along just in the D drive. The enterprise rules says that no apps should use the standard C drive and all apps on a server needs to installed on the D drive. C is only for OS related files.